# why can't I import separately from the method declaration?(java)

Tags: java, eclipse, import, base64, decode

I wrote a simple program to decode a base64 encoded String I have. I searched using eclipse for a method to do that and found out that the method `javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(String s)` does exactly that. I found out that when I'm using the full location of the method, the program is working fine:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
String s = "cGFzc3dvcmQ6IGlsb3ZlbXlzZWxmISEx";
byte[] converted = javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(s);
System.out.println(new String(converted));
}
```

but for some reason, when I'm trying to import the location, eclipse is giving me an error:

import:

```
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.*;
```

new line 3 in the first code:

```
 byte[] converted = javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(s);
```

error I get on new line 3:

```
 The method parseBase64Binary(String) is undefined for the type **name of class**
```

I'd be happy for explanations.

Comment: use import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter; instead of import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.*;

Comment: @antonio I tried that, it gives the same error, and anyway I think the asterisk is required.

Comment: `import` is for importing *types*. `import static` is for importing *static methods*, and that's what you're trying to do here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do a `static` import:

```
import static javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.*;
```

or

```
import static javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary;
```

and then you will be able to do:

```
byte[] converted = parseBase64Binary(s);
```

More info:

- [Static imports in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html#staticimport)

Comment: Great! it worked! I'd be happy for a short explenation or a reference to one.

Comment: Checkout the link I provided. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I understood the problem and the program is working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

```
import static javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.*;
```

then -

```
byte[] converted = parseBase64Binary(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `.*` in `javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.*;`:

```
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String s = "cGFzc3dvcmQ6IGlsb3ZlbXlzZWxmISEx";
        byte[] converted = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(s);
        System.out.println(new String(converted));
    }
}
```

Comment: Np :) I would avoid static imports. It makes your code more unreadable, since it looks like one of your own class methods.